# Does user have to load all 400kb of three.min.js?

Tags: networking, three.js, browser-cache

i'm working on the project that need the file can load really fast on web so i want that file is around 1mb, i see the three.min.js file is 400kb, that is too much for me, my question is:

Does user have to load all 400kb of three.min.js file or they only have to load what scripts the project need in three.min.js file?

( when i press f12 on chrome and go to network tab, i see the three.min.js in my project with 110kb size and 400kb content, that 110kb size is what i have only load right? )

Comment: well, if you know that your app only needs some core functionality, you can go ahead and build your own version of three.min.js that includes only the core functionality, for example. See the github instructions on how to build the project. 
On a second thought, 3D Data is still quite expensive and a obj or collada file can easily be 5 megabytes, so if you want high detailed stuff in your app, you should better get used to higher than usual file sizes.  
Last but not least, three.js is a client-oriented technology. I myself don't know about how to shift stuff to the server-side of things.

Answer (score 1):

When using JS framework keep in mind

> if you know that your app only needs some core functionality, you can
>   go ahead and build your own version of customized JS.

the same about when you use `three.js` customize that to prevent load 400KB on client side.